# How do i define this jsonSchema rule

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have the jsonSchema like below

```
[{
                        "path": [
                            "General",
                            "label"
                        ],
                        "type": "label",
                        "label": "Calculate Losses From Sub-Peril(s)",
                        "required": true
                    },
                    {
                        "path": [
                            "General",
                            "fire"
                        ],
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "default": true,
                        "label": "Fire"

                    },
                    {
                        "path": [
                            "General",
                            "fireSmoke"
                        ],
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "default": false,
                        "label": "Fire and Smoke"

                    }
                ],
```

I have the jsonSchema Rule as below. So if the user unchecks both fire and Fire and Smoke i want to fire a notification. How do i define JsonSchema Rule. Can some one fix this? I have the below rule but it gives me parser error. Atleast one checkbox has to be selected.

```
{
            "path": [
                "General",
                "fire"
            ],
            "effect": "fireNotification",
            "notification": {
                "type": "warning",
                "message": "At least one Sub-Peril must be selected",
                "notificationID": "fire",
                "dismissible": "false"
            },
            "condition": {
                "operator": "oneOf": {
                    "properties": {
                        "fire": {
                            "enum": [
                                true
                            ]
                        },
                        "fireSmoke": {
                            "enum": [
                                true
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid in two ways, both on the same line:

> `"operator": "oneOf": {`

- After `"operator":`, you need another opening brace (`{`) (and a matching closing brace later on.
- The value of `"oneOf":` should be an array, so you need to add an opening bracket (`[`) there (and a matching closing bracket later on).

Further, you say "At least one checkbox has to be selected", but you are using a "oneOf" rule, not "anyOf".  With "oneOf", if both properties are true, the validation will fail.

Comment: does not work
            "condition": {
             "operator": {
              "oneOf": [{
                  "properties" : {
                  "fire": {
                                        "enum": [
                                            true
                                        ]
                                    },
                  }
                  },
                  {
               "properties" : {
               "fireSmoke": {
                "enum": [
                 true
                ]
               }

Comment: "does not work" is not very specific. *what* isn't working? what happens, and what did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Above is the rule that i have defined in the comment. I am expecting a notification to be fired if both are unchecked. I do not get any notification.

Comment: You should check your tooling documentation to see if the notification will fire if the condition *fails*, or if it *passes*. I don't know what tool you are using; I only know about how JSON Schemas are evaluated.